# absolute positioned div is not showing background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the background image of the absolutely positioned div. but that div would never show off.. 
[fiddle here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Ic_arrow_drop_down_48px.svg)

```
<div class=""> City: 
    <span class="displaycity" style="display: none;">xxxx 
    </span> 
    <span class="contentbox editcitytext" style="display: inline-block;"> 
        <input type="text" value="xxxx" class="citynamebox"> 
        <div style="position: absolute; color: brown; z-index: 3333; top: -101px; left: 90px;" class="validationmessagecomposed">
            <div style=" border:1px solid brown; padding:10px;background-color:white;">Please check for invalid characters
            </div>
            <div style="height:7px;  text-align:center;background- image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Ic_arrow_drop_ down_48px.svg); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:60px; position:absolute; top:93px;">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </span> 
    <span class="editcitybutton">Update 
    </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Clean up your code...

Comment: Your fiddle just links to an SVG file.

Comment: @Michael that was just on the fly... the one I used on my side was png..

Comment: if you're lazy in your question you can expect lazy answers

Comment: @ElGavilan what do you mean clean up the code?

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to create your own select box? Possibly look into just using the browsers select box and styling it to use your svg arrow. Take a look at this http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: @Benneb10 actually I am displaying the error message while typin the cityname.. I am placing the arrow to connect to text box where the user is typing..

Comment: Nobody noticed that I have entered div element inside the span .. :D

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say for sure - but you never set a width, which would be required for an absolutely positioned div. Try adding a border to the div to see if it has a width/height.